# Why is the actual value of this variable not being used as the index number of the object I'm trying to return

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, web-audio-api

This has been driving me bonkers since Monday June 6 2022, I really hope someone can tell me what I am doing wrong.

I have a music machine written (as a hobby/learning experience) in JavaScript using the Web Audio API and I'm trying to do something very simple:- update a variable value via a user interface, then use the new value of the variable to reference an array index.

In English! The user should be able to change the octave via a slider on the UI.

What I have is:

- a slider to set a value
- a variable to hold the slider value
- an array of object literals with key/value pairs that hold note frequencies (each object holds an octave)
- a programmed keyboard key 'Y'

What should happen:

- press keyboard key 'Y' to play a note
- a note should play in a specific octave
- moving the slider should change the value of the variable
- the value of the variable should be used to reference the index of an array
- pressing key 'Y' should play a note in a different octave (or return undefined)

What is actually happening:

- pressing keyboard key 'Y' plays a note
- moving the slider changes the value of the variable
- pressing key 'Y' again plays the same note in the same octave
- the current value of the variable set by the user is not being used to reference the specific array index

The code for my music machine is pretty chunky, so I've managed to reproduce the problem I'm having in the code below, I was rather hoping that by doing this I would be able to see what is going wrong, but, alas no! :o(

For the sake of brevity, the array holding the scales has just four indexes, 0 & 1 should return undefined, index 2 should return `440` and index 2 should return `880`

```js
// get the range slider and label from the document
const slider = document.getElementById("slider");
const labelVal = document.getElementById("label");

// var to hold the value of the slider
// We'll use this as the index value later
let oct = 2;

// add an event listener to the slider
window.addEventListener("change", handelChange, false);

// the change event handler
function handelChange(event) {
  // set the value of var oct to the slider value
  oct = parseFloat(slider.value);
  console.log("oct Value:", oct);

  // set the label content to equal value of `oct`
  labelVal.innerHTML = oct;

  return oct;
}

// Create the audio context
const actx = new AudioContext();

// function to call `function createOsc(freq)`
function playNote(freq) {
  ceateOsc(freq);
}

// function to create an audio graph that
// starts and stops the oscillator
function ceateOsc(freq) {
  // create the audio nodes
  const osc = actx.createOscillator();
  const vol = actx.createGain();

  // set the nodes' values
  osc.frequency.value = freq;
  vol.gain.value = 0.1;

  // connect the nodes to the audio context destintion
  osc.connect(vol).connect(actx.destination);

  // start & stop the oscillator
  osc.start();
  osc.stop(actx.currentTime + 1);
}

// array of objects holding musical note frequencies
let scale = [{}, // return undefined
  {}, // return undefined
  {
    A: 440, // return 440
  },
  {
    A: 880, // return 880
  },
];

// map keyboard to notes using var `oct`
// for the index number of array `scale`
const notes = {
  // scale[0].A should undefined
  // scale[1].A should undefined
  // scale[2].A should return 440
  // scale[3].A should return 880
  y: scale[oct].A,
};

// ************* Listen For Keyboard Input START ************ \\
window.addEventListener("keydown", keydownHandler, false);

function keydownHandler(event) {
  const key = event.key;
  const freq = notes[key];
  console.log("keydown event: oct val =", oct, "frequency =", freq);
  // if our notes object has this keyboard key defined
  // play the note:
  if (freq) {
    playNote(freq);
  } else {
    console.log("Only key 'Y' can play a note");
  }
}
// ************* Listen For Keyboard Input END ************ \\
```

```html
<h3>Test To Set Index Via User Interface</h3>

<p>Press key 'Y' to play note 'A'</p>
<p>Set slider to value 2 or 3 to change the octave</p>
<p>
  <!-- Range input: value to be used as the index number -->
  <input type="range" id="slider" min="0" max="3" value="2" /><label id="label" for="setOctave">2</label
      >
    </p>
```

What I've tried:

- If I manually set the index like this: `scale[3].A` key 'Y' plays note A @ 880hz
- If I manually set the index like this:  `scale[2].A` key 'Y' plays note A @ 440hz
- If I manually set the index like this: `scale[0].A` key 'Y' returns `undefined`

Also, if I manually set the initial value of the var `oct` key 'Y' returns the correct note/octave.

I've included `console.log(oct)` at various points in the code including the point of `keydown` and at each point we can see that the value of `oct` is equal to the value of the slider. In fact, the value of `oct` is actually being used to update the UI 'slider text value' shown to the user, however, the current value of `oct` is not being used at this point in  the code `scale[oct].A`

Am I missing something completely obvious here or is there something going on that I am just not aware of?

I much would much appreciate any feedback on this at all.

Thanks.

Comment: `y: scale[oct].A,` oct stays whatever oct is at that statement

Comment: You never do anything with `oct` after it's initially initialized and the `notes` array is created. You update its value, but that value is never read again, AFAICT.

Comment: (With the caveat that I found the code a little hard to reason about. But I did appreciate the Handel pun.)

Comment: Your comments have been a moment of clarity for me, I think my problem was I had no idea how to make sure that the value of `oct` was read again, I truly am a novice :¬/ The answer below helps me to get there. All feed back has been very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialize `notes`, the value of `oct` is *only accessed once* at the point that object is created. Subsequent changes to `oct` will not have any effect on the value of the "y" property.

One option to fix that would be to have the value of "y" be a getter function:

```
const notes = {
  // scale[0].A should undefined
  // scale[1].A should undefined
  // scale[2].A should return 440
  // scale[3].A should return 880
  get y() { return scale[oct].A; }
};
```

Comment: Yes!, thanks indeed for sharing this, it certainly gets (excuse the pun) me there! Using this method I would need a getter function for each keyboard key programmed. Am I right in thinking there may be a more eloquent way to write this?

Comment: @Fishbite well there might be an alternative, yes. You could compute the note frequencies on the fly probably, perhaps with the help of a lookup table to pre-compute intermediate math.

Comment: Hmm! At the moment I'm pre-calculating the frequencies like this: `class Octave {
  constructor(a) {
    this.C = a * Math.pow(2, -9 / 12);
    this.Cs = a * Math.pow(2, -8 / 12);.
    this.A = a;
    this.As = a * Math.pow(2, 1 / 12);
    this.B = a * Math.pow(2, 2 / 12);
  }`  followed by: `const A4 = 440;
let scale = [];

for (let i = -4; i < 4; i++) {
  let a = A4 * Math.pow(2, i);
  let octave = new Octave(a);

  scale.push(octave);
}`

Comment: @Fishbite if you want even temperment then precomputing the twelfth root of 2 is probably all you need to do. Then you can multiply by that and add the base frequency for the desired octave.

Comment: Yes, equal temperament is the objective here, each octave divided into 12 equally spaced notes with the twelfth root of 2 being written `Math.pow(2, 1/12)` But I'm struggling to understand what you mean by your last sentence _Then you can multiply by that and add the base frequency for the desired octave_ (apologies if I'm being a little dense, I'm just learning this stuff...) My base frequency of the octave is A no? All other notes are calculated from this.

Comment: Well it doesn't really matter; you just need a reference frequency for the scale. On a piano people usually consider middle C to be the "base", but with equal temperment  it doesn't matter, so A works fine too. Once you have A, then A# is the frequency of A multiplied by the twelfth root of 2. B is A multiplied by 2 times the twelfth root of 2, and so on. You can then go up or down by octaves by doubling or halving the frequencies.

Comment: Actually that's not quite right; A# is A times 2 times the twelfth root of 2. Anyway with a calculator you can easily figure it out.